# Beautifulsoup replace similar string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some strings in str format like:

```
a = "/a/b/0"
b = "/a/b/10"
c = "/a/c/100"
```

and I want to replace them with ""
I just tried:

```
a.replace('/a/b/0','')
b.replace('/a/b/10','')
c.replace('/a/c/100,'')
```

but doing it this way looks idiotic...
is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You can try changing the encoding or try a different parser to eliminate those characters.

Comment: how about this? `import re; re.sub(r'\B[\/\w]+','',your_variable)`

Answer (score 0):

Using the package `re`, you can capture similar patterns. The concrete expression would depend on what all do you want to (not) capture. If you wanted to replace everything in the form **/a/[character]/[number]**, the corresponding regular expression would be `\/a\/\w\/\d+` like so:

```
import re
a = re.sub("\/a\/\w\/\d+", "", a)
b = re.sub("\/a\/\w\/\d+", "", b)
c = re.sub("\/a\/\w\/\d+", "", c)
```

The way in which you capture all the variables `a`, `b`, `c` depends on your purpose: you can store them in a list, then apply the substitution using list comprehension and cast the results back into the individual variables like so:

```
import re
spam = [a,b,c]
spam = [re.sub("\/a\/\w\/\d+", "", x) for x in spam]
a,b,c = spam
```

Or if there is a part of your program before this replacement where you extracted `a`, `b`, `c` from a string `s`, you can do the replacement before this extraction:

```
import re
s = ("\/a\/\w\/\d+", "", s)
...
#your code extracting a,b,c from s
```

But since we don't know how you got `a`, `b`, `c` and whether they are the only variables you want to change, it is hard to give a concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

lets say you store the strings in a collection

```
a = "/a/b/0"
b = "/a/b/10"
c = "some other stuff"
d = "/a/c/100"

strings = [a,b,c,d]

for string in strings:
    if string.startswith('/a'):
        strings[strings.index(string)] = ''
```

if you

```
print(strings) 
['', '', 'some other stuff', '']
```

then you can reassing the values with the collection's index.